# How to disable browser convert charteters to unicode

Tags: angular, typescript, browser

I have date:
 //in my code :

```
          2017-10-30T12:26:29.094+0200
```

//in browser URl link:

```
           2017-10-30T12:26:29.094+0200
```

//i'm trying to convert To in my code:

```
          2017-10-30T12:26:29.094%2B0200
```

//in browser URl link:

```
         2017-10-30T12:26:29.094%252B0200
```

i need convert only + to %2B

Comment: The last one, `%252B`, indicates that the date has been URI encoded twice. When does this happen?

What is the flow of the value, and are you using any library or framework to render the link? A simple
`const t = new Date().toISOString(); a.href = "?date=" + encodeURIComponent(t);` 
will not cause a double encoding.

Comment: I'm using Java Spring Framework but I can't Edit it.